# operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to write a function in sml that takes in a list of pairs and returns pair of two list of all the elements
Meaning if the input is [(1, 2.0), (2, 3.0)]
The output should be ([1, 2], (2.0, 3.0))

```
fun divide nil = (nil , nil)
| divide [(a, b)::nil] = ([a], [b])
| divide [(a, b)::myTl] =
    let
      val (x, y) = divide myTl
      
    in
      (a::x, b::y)
    end
```

;

Never the less the sml interpreter returns the following err

```
Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
operator domain: ('Z * 'Y) list list
operand:         ('Z * 'Y) list
in expression:
divide myTl
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing is because you've (inadvertently) declared a function with domain `('a * 'b) list list` due to your input patterns, so your recursive call is not well typed.

The most straightforward fix is to correct for the incorrect use of `[ ]` around the argument to the function---this is making a singleton list, instead of just grouping the pattern. Thus you'd want to use `( )` instead.

```
fun divide nil = (nil , nil)
  | divide ((a, b)::nil) = ([a], [b])
  | divide ((a, b)::myTl) =
    let
      val (x, y) = divide myTl
      
    in
      (a::x, b::y)
    end
```

Your second base case is also extraneous, so we could further revise this to

```
fun divide [] = ([], [])
  | divide ((a, b)::xs) =
    let
      val (x, y) = divide xs   
    in
      (a::x, b::y)
    end
```